# Calculate World Coordinates from Normalized Device Coordinates

Tags: java, android, math, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm currently trying to register touches on the screen in World Space.
I first convert them to normalized Device Coordinates and then try to multiply a point at the near side of the normalized cube (z = -1) and a point at the far side of the normalized cube (z = 1) with the inverted ProjectionViewMatrix to get a Line between them. 
My approach so far:

```
//Calculate ProjectionViewMatrix
Matrix.multiplyMM(projectionViewMatrix,0,perspectiveProjectionMatrix,0,viewMatrix,0);

//Calculate Inverse
Matrix.invertM(invertedProjectionViewMatrix,0,projectionViewMatrix,0);

float[] nearPoint = {x, y, -1, 1};
float[] farPoint = {x, y, 1, 1};

float[] nearPointWorldSpace = new float[4];
float[] farPointWorldSpace = new float[4];

Matrix.multiplyMV(nearPointWorldSpace,0, invertedProjectionViewMatrix,0, nearPoint,0);
Matrix.multiplyMV(farPointWorldSpace,0, invertedProjectionViewMatrix,0, farPoint,0);

perspectiveDevide(nearPointWorldSpace);
perspectiveDevide(farPointWorldSpace);
```

Where perspectiveDevide is defined as:

```
private static void perspectiveDevide(float[] vector) {
    vector[0] /= vector[3];
    vector[1] /= vector[3];
    vector[2] /= vector[3];
}
```

Now what I should get is a near and far point that have the same or very similar X/Y-Coordinates, because my Camera is right above the lookAt and with no angle.
However what I do get is this:

NearPointWorld:

```
[0] -0.002805814
[1] 0.046295937
[2] 1.9
[3] 9.999999
```

FarPointWorld:

```
[0] -2.8057494
[1] 46.294872 
[2] -97.99771
[3] 0.010000229
```

Any Ideas what might be wrong?

**EDIT:**

Here's my code for the View and Projection Matrix:

Projection:

```
Matrix.perspectiveM(perspectiveProjectionMatrix,0, 60, (float) width / (float) height, 0.1f, 100f);
```

View:

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix,0, 
            0,0,2, 
            0,0,0, 
            0,1,0);
```

Comment: you should also set `vector[3]=1;` in perspective divide

Comment: Yeah, I did that, but it doesn't affect my problem sadly

Comment: Actually, your results look reasonable. If you remove the camera's shift by (0, 0, 2), then `farWorldPoint` is about 1000 times `nearWorldPoint`, which is exactly the ratio of your znear and zfar plane distances. And the points are on a ray with the camera. So I don't see any problem with your results. X/Y coordinates of both points will only be equal if you unproject the screen center.

Comment: Of course! You're right. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nico Schertler pointed out, these results are actuallly reasonable.
To get the correct X/Y Coordinates I had to unproject the screen center.